# Как удалить файл, если он находится в другом каталоге?

Tags: php

Как можно при обращении к файлу `http://мойсайт.ру/home/test.php?del`, который расположен в одном каталоге, по адресу `http://мойсайт.ру/home/test.php`, удалить файл, который находится в другом каталоге, по адресу `http://мойсайт.ру/dir/cat/default.tpl`. Таким способом файл не удаляется:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['del'])) {
    unlink("http://мойсайт.ру/dir/cat/default.tpl");
}
?>
```

Что я делаю не так? Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: зачем вы URL-файла передаете? вам нужен локальный путь.

Comment: Не путайте `url` и путь к файлу в локальной файловой системе

Comment: попробуйте открыть файл, похоже вы путаетесь в адресе

Comment: Запустите отладку и посмотрите что происходит. Вероятно у сервера, запущенным под одним пользователем, нет прав на удаление файла.